# How to write rails Controller to simulate update twitter-API like?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I want to write rails controller to allow user to update resource through json or xml like [update status](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses%C2%A0update) in twitter.

---

I tried to create some dummy controller like

```
def visit
...
end
```

and add route

```
map.connect 'users/visit', :controller => 'users', :action => 'visit', :conditions => {:method => :post}
```

but when I tired post some data with `curl -d "var=1" http://localhost:3000/users/visit`
It's not work, after that I tried some basic user/create with `curl -d "var=1 http://localhost:3000/users`, but this not work either.Do I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

The default controller stub generated with the `script/generator scaffold` already provides support for XML requests. You just need to customize it.

[This post](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/3/27/web-services-rails-style) might give you a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at John Nunemaker's [Twitter RubyGem](http://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter/). It includes a [status update example](http://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter/blob/31341b3593868ef34935e19a366b839bba63446d/examples/update.rb).